# Picture Labels with leader line from point without annotation?

Tags: arcgis-10.1, labeling, arcgis-desktop, annotation, maplex

The closest thing I have is using a line call out in the text background, then placing the picture in the line call out border. But the picture tiles throughout. Is what I am trying to do even possible without adding graphics or annotation?

Basically I want to do what Google earth does automatically with the placement of their labels?

Any extensions besides Maplex? Any tools or solutions?

Comment: Are you using ArcGIS for Desktop? If so, what version? If 10.1, why not Maplex which is free for you?

Comment: Yes 10.1. I have been using Maplex, but its doesn't have the option to show just one picture in the line call out border. It shows it in the form of tiles of that picture. My other thread with pics explains its better. http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/85128-Picture-Labels-with-leader-line-from-point-without-annotation

Comment: Ever heard of converting bitmap to glyph (font)?

Answer (score 3):

I found what looks like a possible solution for leadered symbols described in a [BGCARTO blog post entitled Leadered Symbols in ArcMap](http://www.bgcarto.com/leadered-symbols-in-arcmap/).

And another [article entitled Use PNGs as ArcGIS Picture Marker Symbols in ArcWatch](http://www.esri.com/news/arcwatch/0113/use-pngs-as-arcgis-picture-marker-symbols.html) I saw today may be useful for making your picture markers look great.

Comment: http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/85128-Picture-Labels-with-leader-line-from-point-without-annotation?p=300994#top The second thread I posted is where I am currently at. Works great besides that when vertical or west position, the offset isn't matching up to the logo.